# How to check if a static file in web server is updated or not?

Tags: java, api, webserver, last-modified

Any Java API in client side can check its modified date?

Comment: Client side means what exactly? Are you getting the file from the server via HttpClient or something similar? If so, you need to look at the HTTP headers (Last-Modified in particular). Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry I mean in client side. The question is revised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to check the Last-Modified value on a page, assuming the server returns one.

This request uses the HTTP [HEAD method](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) to return only the headers for the resource:

```
URL url = new URL(
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
    .openConnection();
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
httpConnection.connect();
long lastModified = httpConnection.getLastModified();
if (lastModified != 0) {
  System.out.println(new Date(lastModified));
} else {
  System.out.println("Last-Modified not returned");
}
httpConnection.disconnect();

// TODO: error handling
```

HttpURLConnection is adequate for some things, but if you want a more rounded API, have a look at [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [lastModified](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) method in [java.io.File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to find out the last time a file was modified.

Comment: Sorry I mean in client side. The question is revised.